# docpad-plugin-thumbnails appears to hang

Tags: docpad

Symptom...

docpad run results in the usual messages but it never gets past:

> Currently on writeFiles at 45/45 100% =================================================

Environment -

osx 10.8.3
node v0.10.0
npm i.2.14
docpad 6.34.2
ImageMagick v6.8.5-3, which has been confirmed working from the command line

Steps to reproduce...

- Install kitchensink skeleton (or the jade and adapt the coffeekup code in example)
- Install docpad-plugin-associatedfiles
  and docpad-plugin-thumbnails
- Create an associate-files directory in Files and drop in another directory called 'gallery' with some .jpg's with no spaces in the filenames
- Create a new page called gallery.html.coffee and cut and paste the coffeeKup example from thumbnails' read me file :) - see below.. [I've also tried simplifying it down to the bare functionality to show the thumbnails, by cutting out the checks on file-types and the links to the original sized images.]
- docpad run and watch whilst it doesn't finish...

Observations -

If you remove the reference to getThumbnails and just list the associated files it all works peachy.

Filenames for the thumbnails that would be generated show up in the generated HTML file - but the thumbnails do not show up in the out directory (or anywhere else as far as I could find)

So questions...

- am I missing the startlingly obvious? (here's hoping)
- how do I inspect docpad.log?
- I read the instructions for debugging, but so far I've not made sense of them enough to step into any code - sorry - I'm a real novice.

Thanks for any input,

The page looks like this:

```
---
layout: default
title: Gallery
---
image_exts = ['jpg', 'JPG', 'jpeg', 'JPEG', 'png', 'PNG']
images = @getDocument().getAssociatedFiles().findAll({extension: $in: image_exts}).toJSON()
for image in images
    a href: image.url, -> img src: @getThumbnail(image.url, w: 100, h: 100), alt: image.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I used the command:

```
$ docpad --debug 7 run
```

If you get the error "spawn ENOENT", you must install graphicsmagick, because the gm library needs some configuration if you use imagemagick.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command:

```
npm install --save docpad-plugin-thumbnails
```

I was facing the similar issue and it worked for me.. hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the plugin to [use imageMagick](https://github.com/rantecki/docpad-plugin-thumbnails#imagemagick) in your `docpad.coffee`?

```
plugins:
    thumbnails:
        imageMagick: true
```